# changing jquery 'this' and 'next', to a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working with the following code;

```
<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"if($(this).next('div').css('display') == 'none') { $(this).next('div').show('fast'); } else { $(this).next('div').hide('fast'); } return false;\">Link</a>
```

What i need to do, is change the part `if($(this).next('div')`, to target a specific element ID, not the next one from current location.

Any ideas are much appreciated, as well as explinations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you escaping your "s?

Comment: If possible, always attach the handlers via jQuery (i.e. `$('a').click(...)`) instead of adding it to your HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$('#myDiv')` to select an element with `id="myDiv"`. Also, you should be using the `toggle` function for this:

```
<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"$('#myDiv').toggle('fast');\">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Target the ID of the element you want to change. E.g.

```
<a href="#" onClick="if('#myElement').css('display') == 'none') { $('#myElement').show('fast'); } else { $('#myElement').hide('fast'); } return false;">Link</a>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement">Whatever</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is convert:

```
 <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"if($(this).next('div').css('display') == 'none') { $(this).next('div').show('fast'); } else { $(this).next('div').hide('fast'); } return false;\">Link</a>
```

into:

```
<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"if($('#SomeElement').css('display') == 'none') { $('#SomeElement').show('fast'); } else { $('#SomeElement').hide('fast'); } return false;\">Link</a>
```

????

But of course, I'm assuming that there is only one `SomeElement` on the page. I'm trying to make sure I understand the question...